# Terraform aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm An error occurred contacting the server

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm creating CloudWatch alarm with Terraform, e.g.:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "terraform_cloudwatch_metric_alarm_CPUUtilization" {
alarm_name = "terraform_cloudwatch_metric_alarm_CPUUtilization"
alarm_description = "terraform_cloudwatch_metric_alarm_CPUUtilization"
comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
evaluation_periods = "1"
metric_name = "CPUUtilization"
namespace = "AWS/EC2"
period = "300"
statistic = "Average"
threshold = "90"
dimensions = {
    "Instance­Id" = "${aws_instance.terraform_instance.id}"
}
```

}

But I'm getting **An error occurred contacting the server**:
[image]

When I'm creating the same from console it works fine:
[image]

Any ideas why and how to fix it?

**PS** Temporary workaround is to add `local-exec` to `aws_instance`:

  `provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOF
    aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm \
    --alarm-name "cloudwatch_metric_alarm_CPUUtilization" \
    --alarm-description "cloudwatch_metric_alarm_CPUUtilization" \
    --no-actions-enabled \
    --metric-name "CPUUtilization" \
    --namespace "AWS/EC2" \
    --statistic "Average" \
    --dimensions "Name=InstanceId,Value=${aws_instance.terraform_instance.id}" \
    --period "300" \
    --unit "Percent" \
    --evaluation-periods "1" \
    --threshold "90" \
    --comparison-operator "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold" \
    --treat-missing-data "missing"
    EOF
  }`

Comment: After a little searching, I'm wondering if this is a CloudWatch issue (and not with TF)... Have you tried mucking with the params (name, threshold, period, etc.)?

Comment: @KJH sorry, I haven't got what you mean.. But I faced the same issue with metrics for RDS, ElastiCache, etc.

Comment: sorry, I meant try adjusting some of the parameters in the `aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm` Terraform resource to see if something may help. It does seem like it's a CloudWatch problem and not a TF issue. Perhaps reach out to AWS via their forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in SOFT HYPHEN present in dimension name, both VSCode and Sublime 3 showed code normally:
[image: VSCode]

[image: Sublime]

only Vim/nano were showing correctly:
[image: nano]